# Lucene - Busca simples com query

Tags: java, query, parser, lucene

Estou tentando fazer buscas em um index feito com Lucene que me foi enviado. São buscas simples que não estão dando certo...

```
package portugues;

//https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.management.Query;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

public class Buscador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    IndexReader reader =   DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get("/home/janaina/Bureau/projet_java/MyLuceneIndex")));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("contents", analyzer);
    Query query1 = parser.parse("pomme");
    Query query2 = parser.parse("pomme" AND "banane");
    Query query3 = parser.parse("pomme" OR "banane");
    Query query4 = parser.parse("pomme*");


    System.out.println(query1);
    System.out.println(query2);
    System.out.println(query3);
    System.out.println(query4);

}

}
```

Eu só preciso encontrar algumas palavras usando Query Parser Syntax. Desculpa se a pergunta é besta. É que sou iniciante... Obrigada!